# How to get Ubuntu to use as much Resources as Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, 13.04, overheating, fan, environment

Well.. I love Ubuntu, but it causes my laptop to use resources up, and I don't even know why. it even cause my laptop's fan to run louder and heat up (not overheat, but it does get hot). As soon as I switch to the Lubuntu desktop environment, and do the exact same thing, which is browse the internet using Google Chrome (Uses on tab most of the time) , the laptop's fan is not only quieter, but the computer cool down. I like using Ubuntu for the features but I like Lubuntu for the use of less resources. Is there anyway to apply the use of less resources to Ubuntu to make the laptop just as cool and tranquil as on Ubuntu?

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. Even though I love the bells and whistle, I do not use them all the time. I do not use them all of the time. Even though I love Ubuntu, If I want a quiet computer, Lubuntu is just for me. Isn't Lubuntu made from Ubuntu? it has a lot of stuff from it even if I'm using it just as another desktop environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable the 3D effects and a bunch of other parameters you might get close. But that is the reason why Lubuntu exists, those optimizations have been done for you so you don't need to do it yourself. Lubuntu might not have all the bells and whistles but that's why its less resource hungry

Basically its all Ubuntu, they just use a different Desktop environment. The Desktop environment manages the windows, integration of applications, services, indicators, task-bars and all that. The bigger the code foot print the more resources, the more CPU, the more heat...memory and such.

I use the Gnome Classic interface personally as it is more "Windows XP" ish which is desktop focused. The new Unity interface is not usable in my opinion unless you have a tablet. Everyone likes a different way of operating and Ubuntu has all these desktop environments so you have the choice. Sometimes that decision is because of power restrictions, sometimes its a personal taste like in my case.

In the end its a compromise between features/taste and what your Computer can cope with.